# Does the LLDB command have any effect on the source code?

Tags: lldb

I am Set a breaking point in the current project and output the value of the object as po among Expressions of LLDB

I found that nil is included when the value of the object is not checked with po, and the value is well entered when the value is checked.

The po command is an abbreviation of print object, and I know that it just prints the description of the object itself. Do you know the reason for the difference between checking the value with po and not doing it?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of your code, and exactly how you do this with and without `po`? Do you use `p` instead?

Comment: Yes i use `po`,, I don't get the output I want when I use p

`
`

Comment: i add my code on comment

Comment: I solved this error.. I did not understand the situation in which po works well
So, how to solve it was that nil was entered because it was declared as a weak variable. thank you